# AVCaptureDevice videoZoomFactor always Out of Range

Tags: ios, ios7, avfoundation, avcapturedevice

I'm trying to set the zoom level of a camera by this code:

```
 AVCaptureDevice *videoDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];


 if ([videoDevice lockForConfiguration:nil]) {
     float newzoom=1.3;
     videoDevice.videoZoomFactor = newzoom;
     [videoDevice unlockForConfiguration];
 }
```

This code doesn't not works in ios 7(it works in ios 9), it cause always an exception:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 'videoZoomFactor out of range'
```

I can't find information but the zoom range in ios 7 seems to be "from 1 to 2". But every value i have tried to set for the float newzoom cause the exception... How i can do to set the videoZoomFactor in Ios 7?

EDIT

I have decided to hide the zoom button when the device doesn't support the zoom. So this is the code i have used:

```
AVCaptureDevice *videoDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
float max=videoDevice.activeFormat.videoMaxZoomFactor;
float min=MIN(videoDevice.activeFormat.videoMaxZoomFactor, 4.0f);


if (max==1 && min==1) {

    [ZoomButton setHidden:YES];
}
```

If max and min are equals to 1 means that the device doesn't support this kind of zoom. It seems to work... There is a better way to do this check? I can't find a list of the supported devices in documentation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to apple documentation, if the device's videoMaxZoomFactor is 1, then zoom is not available:

> If the device's videoZoomFactor property is assigned a larger value,
>   an NSRangeException will be thrown. **A maximum zoom factor of 1
>   indicates no zoom is available**.

So in your case, you could hide the zoomButton by just checking this property:

```
AVCaptureDevice *videoDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
float max=videoDevice.activeFormat.videoMaxZoomFactor;

if (max==1) {
    [ZoomButton setHidden:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check `videoMaxZoomFactor` before setting `videoZoomFactor` because `videoZoomFactor` is NOT always "from 1.0 to 2.0"  . 
Docs:

> This value is a multiplier. For example, a value of 2.0 doubles the
>   size of an image’s subject (and halves the field of view). **Allowed
>   values range from 1.0 (full field of view) to the value of the active
>   format’s `videoMaxZoomFactor` property**. Setting the value of this
>   property jumps immediately to the new zoom factor. For a smooth
>   transition, use the `rampToVideoZoomFactor:withRate:` method.

Comment: i have edited my question, first of my problem is an incompatibility hardware issue